# Saving a report as PDF on Azure Storage in Business Central

Tags: azure, azure-storage, dynamics-business-central

I am trying to run a report on Business central on cloud and i want to save that report(PDF) directly on azure storage.

i wonder is there anyway to do it on Business Central 365 AL code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the term "Azure Storage" is too broad! What storage? File? Blob? Data Lake?
But the process as follows:
0. Have a look/learn and try to write a code in AL to access to the chosen Storage option. They have nice REST APIs
1. Save the report to as Stream using SAVEASPDF
2. Upload the stream to the Storage using it's REST API